# "Action not allowed" error on file.setOwner Apps Script (Google Drive API)

Tags: google-apps-script

Getting error message `"Action not allowed (line 3, file "Code")"`

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("0Bz99xGttsifZR2ItTU5pdXXXXX");
  file.setOwner("XXXXX@gmail.com");
}
```

I'm the owner of the file, so I don't know why it's not allowed.

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: .mp4 file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer to anyone, but only Google Drive extensions, ie. the files that doesn't take space in Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer ownership is only possible within a domain. If it were allowed you could fill up the drive of someone in another domain with garbage, resulting in a small Denial of Service attack on that user.